# SQLZoo advanced query

Tags: mysql, sql

In one of the problems for the SQLZoo SELECT within SELECT Tutorial (http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial), you are given a table called 'world' that contains all the countries in the world with the following fields: name, continent, area, population, and gdp.

Here are the sample records from the world table that the site shows you for this problem:

```
name    continent   area    population  gdp
Afghanistan Asia    652230  25500100    20343000000
Albania Europe      28748   2831741     12960000000
Algeria Africa      2381741 37100000    188681000000
Andorra Europe      468     78115       3712000000
Angola  Africa      1246700 20609294    100990000000
...
```

How do I create a query for the following:

'Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations are less than 25000000. Show name, continent and population.'

Comment: The database shown is not complete also, it just includes some info to get an idea of what the table looks like

Comment: Please register for a real account and stop making new throwaway ones to edit clarification into your post.

Comment: Feel free to revert the 3rd party edit if it does not reflect your particular problem then.

Comment: ok - i mean i think the question was solved pretty nicely and i moved on from this but i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the continents where all countries have a small population using MAX

```
SELECT continent
FROM world
GROUP BY continent 
HAVING MAX(population)<25000000
```

You can use that result as a sub query to find every country

```
SELECT name,continent,population
FROM world
WHERE continent IN (
  SELECT continent
  FROM world
  GROUP BY continent
  HAVING MAX(population)<25000000
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get it and was getting frustrated

Answer (score 0):

So you apply, You can use this

```
select name, continent,[population]
from country
where [population] < 25000000
group by name, continent,[population]
```

Comment: QUestion 7 from here: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure if that's working...for chrome it is not

Comment: You're trying to use Subquerys...???